# TableAdapter.Update not saving changes in data

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm looking on the web and in most examples TableAdapter.Update works just fine. I don't know what is wrong in my code, but it's not works for me(data doesnt changes in DataSet or my Access DataBase).
  Hope you can help me solve this problem.

(Sorry for my bad English)

```
 namespace myDB
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void tableSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (tableSelection.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: mainTable.DataSource = компанияBindingSource;
                myBindingNavigator.BindingSource = компанияBindingSource;

                break;
            case 1: mainTable.DataSource = обслуживающийПерсоналBindingSource;
                myBindingNavigator.BindingSource = обслуживающийПерсоналBindingSource;

                break;
            case 2: mainTable.DataSource = персоналBindingSource;
                myBindingNavigator.BindingSource = персоналBindingSource;

                break;
            case 3: mainTable.DataSource = пользовательBindingSource;
                myBindingNavigator.BindingSource = пользовательBindingSource;

                break;
            case 4: mainTable.DataSource = продуктBindingSource;
                myBindingNavigator.BindingSource = продуктBindingSource;

                break;
            case 5: mainTable.DataSource = проектыBindingSource;
                myBindingNavigator.BindingSource = проектыBindingSource;

                break;
            case 6: mainTable.DataSource = разработчикиBindingSource;
                myBindingNavigator.BindingSource = разработчикиBindingSource;

                break;

            default: MessageBox.Show("Проверьте корректность выбранного значения!");
                break;
        }

}



   public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bDDataSet.Разработчики' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.разработчикиTableAdapter.Fill(this.bDDataSet.Разработчики);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bDDataSet.Проекты' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.проектыTableAdapter.Fill(this.bDDataSet.Проекты);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bDDataSet.Продукт' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.продуктTableAdapter.Fill(this.bDDataSet.Продукт);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bDDataSet.Пользователь' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.пользовательTableAdapter.Fill(this.bDDataSet.Пользователь);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bDDataSet.Персонал' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.персоналTableAdapter.Fill(this.bDDataSet.Персонал);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bDDataSet.обслуживающий_персонал' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.обслуживающий_персоналTableAdapter.Fill(this.bDDataSet.обслуживающий_персонал);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bDDataSet.Компания' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.компанияTableAdapter.Fill(this.bDDataSet.Компания);



    }

    public void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        пользовательBindingSource.EndEdit();
        пользовательTableAdapter.Update(bDDataSet.Пользователь);
        bDDataSet.AcceptChanges();




    }







}
}
```

[Screenshot of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJbxz.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
      Validate();
      abcFormBindingSource.EndEdit();
      abcViewFormTableAdapter.UpdateQuery(YourParameter)
      MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
}


catch (System.Exception ex)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Update failed " + ex.ToString());
      return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have method UpdateQuery in my tableAdapter

Comment: Go to your Data Sources > Edit DataSet with Designer Right Click On your Table > add query > next > Choose UPDATE and then insert your update code press next And you have to choose your method name in my case UpdateQuery then finnish

Comment: I find the solution, maybe it will help someone with such problem:
There are 2 copies of the database: 1 in the application folder and 1 in the bin\debug folder. At design time the database in the app folder is used while at run time the other one.

By default in the solution explorer the database is set to COPY ALWAYS to the bin\debug folder which means that the database is alwys overwritten by the one in the application folder.

Solution: I change this property to "COPY IF NEWER" and now it's works.